# Machine Design Softwares for Ubuntu

Tags: windows

Is Design Machine Software like 'Solid works' and 'Uni-graphics' is available for Ubuntu or the same software used in windows can be run in this OS ?

Comment: You can install windows software with `wine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some design packages available in the Ubuntu Software center, and a Google search will provide reviews of their capabilities.  Solidworks itself does not support Linux.  Unigraphics does have a Linux port, although I do not know the cost of this program.

For operation of the Windows based programs, using a virtual machine to emulate Windows does work - I run Solidworks in a Windows XP based in VMWare, and have been quite happy with the performance that I obtain.